# Image generation for visualising analysis in droidbox

Tags: visualization, analysis

I am trying to use 'droidbox' - android application sandbox to analyse apk files. I could do the analysis and see log generated through the terminal itself. Can anybody tell me where or how can I see the images generated for visualisation?

I followed the steps in this page: http://code.google.com/p/droidbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the same problem trying to use DroidBox. If you look at its source in svn, you'll see the code for generating images in external/droidbox.py. For some reason this code is omitted in scripts/droidbox.py of http://droidbox.googlecode.com/files/DroidBox411RC.tar.gz. I managed to get the images by copying the corresponding code to scripts/droidbox.py. No modifications were needed except for the spaces.